# How do people live without line-number mode in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Not sure if it is the right place to ask. Please comment if I've got it wrong.

1. I am personally addicted to line number mode, that is to show the actual number of every line on the left of the screen(like :set nu in vim). It was great help to me. I could directly jump to a certain line without counting the target line number (50 M-g g to jump to line 50) for example.
2. Emacs has no built in support(until recently included the linum mode) for line numbers. Which however do have line number support on the mode line.

The question is: How could people live with only line number support on the mode line. What kind of life style would it be? Just out of curiosity. Not specifically for the task I described above.

Comment: Five and a half years *is* reasonably recent by Emacs standards -- but it's still a pretty decent length of time :)

Answer (score 4):

I'd ask the opposite: why do you want to see line numbers all the time? I practically never need it. The only time which comes to mind is when there is an error message in a shell somwhere and I have to check which line it refers to. But still in those cases there is goto-line.

Line numbers most of the time are useless to me, because the info they give is meaningless. The only exception is errors/warnings like I said above, but in those cases I use jump to error, so I don't have to bother with line numbers even then.

So the modeline indicator is enough for me for those rare cases when I want to know which line I'm on.

Comment: The cases ARE rare, one that I can think up is reviewing code on-line with others(without github or similar things). Now I am just wondering if I've developed a bad habit being too addicted to that and want to make a change.

Answer (score 1):

Just quickly before your questions inevitably gets closed:

I've been using Emacs forever and I'm perfectly fine without line number mode. In fact, I tried it a while ago but didn't warm up to it so I reverted back to just using the mode-line. But then again, I'm a minimalist when it comes to Emacs and try to turn off all unnecessary clutter (menus, toolbar, scrollbars, etc.)

So to actually answer your question (how do people live without line-number mode): *quite comfortably*!